# How to keep the result of an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I often find myself doing something like this:

```
$search = 'some string';
if(strpos($html, $search)!==false){
  $trimmed = substr($html, strpos($html, $search));
  // whole bunch of other stuff
}
```

Is there a way to do this without calling `strpos()` twice? Currently I'm calling it first for the `if()` check, and then again for the execution. This obviously seems inefficient.

Even if I try to go with a ternary operator, I'm still calling `strpos()` twice when I assign it as the true value.

```
$trimmed = strpos($html, $search)!==false ? substr($html, strpos($html, $search)) : false;

if($trimmed!==false){
  // the other stuff  
}
```

What is the best way to keep the result of the if statement so that it doesn't need to be called again within itself?

Comment: `$result = strpos($html, $search); if($result!==false)....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pos = strpos($html, $search);

if ($pos !== false) {
  $trimmed = substr($html, $pos);
}
```

or

```
if (($pos = strpos($html, $search)) !== false) {
  $trimmed = substr($html, $pos);
}
```

Comment: I like the second way, but I can see why the first is clearer.

Comment: Thanks. The second is what I am after. Perhaps not the best example, but I was concerned with error messages popping up on a straight `$pos = strpos($html, $search);` call.

Answer (score 2):

In your ternary you are calling the value of `strpos()`, if its not false, call `strpos()` again and store that against `trimmed`, otherwise if it is `false`, set it to `false`.

You care calling `strpos()` twice for no reason as:

```
strpos($html, $search) == (strpos($html, $search)!==false ? substr($html, strpos($html, $search)) : false;)
```

Just store the value of the function call in a variable and check against that:

```
$trimmed = strpos($html, $search)

if($trimmed!==false){
  // the other stuff  
}
```